# Do we need to avoid criticism of any governments in this stack exchange?

Tags: discussion

Do we need to avoid criticism of any governments in this stack exchange?

I'm not the kind of person who'd launch into a multi-page diatribe within Stack Exchange, but when drafting [Is hanja opposed in North Korea?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/151/is-hanja-opposed-in-north-korea) I was tempted to use a humorous word instead of "opposed".

I decided not to, because I didn't know whether we're trying to be avoided this website being blocked by any governments, but on second thoughts I also don't know whether it's likely to be hurtful to members of the community.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, we need to avoid criticism of any governments.

Stack Exchange is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum. I don't think it is appropriate to employ any criticism for any government that might create a thread of off-topic comments triggered by the use of a particular word or phrase.

A question should be as definitive and objective as possible and any superfluous or unwarranted words or expressions should be avoided.

Comment: 100% agreed. Political arguments in a miles-long comments section are the *last* thing we'll probably want to see.

Comment: Are there any exceptions community can think of, e.g. `misguided grammar reform of year 1234`?

Comment: @qarma I am not sure what you are referring to, but if you can debate whether it was "really' misguided or not, then, it will lead to discussion, not a definitive answer. Did I answer your question?

Comment: Yeah that's the gist. Example was fake on purpose, you know not to offend anyone (and because I'm lazy).